# VBA Excel pie chart plotting, how do i select the correct pie chart?

Tags: excel, charts

I am plotting a lot of piecharts, but the problem i have is selecting the correct pie charts.

But somehow excel gives me the wrong chart, there are two types of Pie charts, i want the one marked in 
this picture with a green circle, however my code gives me the one marked with RED :(

Pie chart selection  ->   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct9pg.jpg

```
     With Sheets("Visualisation").ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=rng.Left, Width:=rng.Width, Top:=rng.Top, Height:=rng.Height)

        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range("F4:H4") '  PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .Chart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        .Chart.SetElement (msoElementPlotAreaShow)
        .Chart.HasLegend = False
        .Chart.ChartType = xlPie

        .Chart.PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Chart.ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse

' more stuff, about placement etc....
     End with
```

I also notice there is a difference in the plot code.

The full blue one shows
=SERIES(;;Data!$F$4;1)
As if it is ONLY showing F4

The correct one shows
=SERIES(;;Data!$F$4:$H$4;1)
Correctly including F, G and H  4..

Any suggestions on how to select the correct one in VBA?

Comment: `.Chart.PlotBy = xlRows` ?

Comment: OMG. so embarrassed..  you are correct, please submit as answer..